# ESP Wemos D1 upload fails

Tags: esp8266, uploading

I try to upload simple code (e.g. blink.ino) to my ESP8266-12 (I have the WeMos D1 breakout board). Until now, that worked without a problem: I had to pull GPIO0 down and then I could upload the compiled sketch.

Since today that does not work any more - but I did not change anything.

I get:

> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

(I know that here are some questions / github issues out there that have the same error, but that was often because GPIO0 wasn't pulled down and the ESP was therefore not in FLASH mode.)

My config is: ESP8266, 80MHz, DIO, 115200, 512K (64K SPIFFS), ck, Serial

When I reset my board, having GPIO0 pulled down, the ESP sends this serial info:

> ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)

The whole debug output is:

```
esptool v0.4.9 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to ck
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM6
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
Uploading 228624 bytes from D:\Users\myusr\AppData\Local\Temp\build9c9ef3bdfe2fccb480bc6e4bac749e41.tmp/Blink.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
    erasing flash
    size: 037d10 address: 000000
    first_sector_index: 0
    total_sector_count: 56
    head_sector_count: 16
    adjusted_sector_count: 40
    erase_size: 028000
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    setting serial port timeouts to 15000 ms
    read 0, requested 1
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
warning: espcomm_send_command: didn't receive command response
warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_BEGIN) failed
closing bootloader
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, GPIO0 has to be LOW **AND** GPIO2 has to be HIGH. It is very important to use pin D3 as GPIO0 and pin D4 as GPIO2 at the WeMos D1 board, because this "routing" is different for other boards and therefore other digital pins are often described.

Comment: Very useful, upvoted.

Comment: @black What exactly did you do to solve the problem. Because I have almost exact problem. It was working fine. Suddenly It started to give this error. So I plugged every cable on wemos just as it is plain. Then using the Blink sketch even it is not uploaded without this problem. So what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I simply updated CH34x driver for esp8266 to v1.4 from v1.3 after that I was able to see a new port option named usbserial 1420 & wchusbserial 1420. after selecting wchusbserial 1420 I was able to upload program successfully. As  my MacOs running on Mojave